# What is the difference between the Nokia TuneIn Radio app and the official one?

Tags: apps

Nokia's got it's own "copy" of TuneIn Radio (with Nokia as the publisher).

It looks identical, but does have a higher version number than the regular/official version. (2.2 vs 2.1).

Release dates also differ (with the official one being "older").

One thought I had was that maybe the Nokia one was optimized for Lumias in some way. Another possibility was that the official app wasn't available in all markets.

Are there any actual differences/which should I be using on my Lumia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe you have answered your own question. Nokia's version would be available in many more regions (countries region and language regions) than the official one. So a user in a region that TuneIn Radio did not publish to would be able to still see Nokia's versions in the Marketplace.

Also, Nokia takes pride in its exclusive collection and wants to release as many apps as possible there. They've signed deals with publishers (EA is a perfect example of that) to bring exclusive apps, and bring already published apps to new regions.